# Average result of last 10 rows

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions, average, sql-limit

I'm trying to find the average figure for the last 10 rows in a database table:

```
select avg(Reading)
from Readings
Order By Rowid
desc limit 10;
```

This pulls the average of all entries in the table, not the last 10. I've tried all sorts of variations but can't get it to work.

Comment: select the last 10 rows and then run the average on those separately.

Comment: Select the last 10 rows as a resultset (subquery in the from clause) then apply the required grouping on that set of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the super quick replies, I tried again and managed to type in the correct syntax this time in the From clause.

Here is the correct answer:

```
select avg(Reading)
from(select Reading
     from Readings
     Order By Rowid desc
     limit 10);
```